# Curl+php не получает данные

Tags: php, curl

Почему не получается получить данные?

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://365cash.co/page/faq");
$html = curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: print_r($html);  - сервер отдает 520-ую ошибку, видимо вы не можете получить доступ к этому сайту с помощью Curl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://365cash.co/page/faq");
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:58.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/58.0');
        $html = curl_exec($ch);
?>
```